# How do I transfer my Ning Network?

Tags: ning

I currently have a Ning network with 1000 members filled with discussion boards, friends, groups and so forth. I heard that Ning is closing its free package?

Is there a way I can export my Ning network to somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grouply](http://www.grouply.com/) offers a direct [import from Ning](http://blog.grouply.com/ning/)

> Grouply is the only Ning alternative
>   that lets you automatically import
>   your Ning Network members and content.
>
> To migrate your Ning Network to
>   Grouply, first create a new social
>   group. Then from within that group’s
>   site, select “Management Menu” from
>   under the Manage tab, then click the
>   “Migrate from Ning” icon.
>
> We’re committed to making your move
>   from Ning to Grouply as seamless as
>   possible. We will continue to enhance
>   the Migration Tool to add features and
>   make it even easier to use. Please
>   contact us at feedback@grouply.com and
>   let us know your feedback and
>   requirements. We’d love to hear from
>   you!